# Use Regex to extract last row on a text

Tags: c#, regex, line

I need to extract only the last row from a multi-line string using regular expressions. I am trying to use a SingleLine pattern like following @"\n(.*?)$" but, unfortunately it extracts the text starting with second line to end. Any hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you do it with `.Split(..)` method of `String`?

Comment: I'd rather use Regex. I thought about it and if no viable solution comes up - probably I will end up using it.

Comment: "I would rather use the more complex and resource intensive solution".

Comment: Your question really has nothing to do with C# in your context.

Comment: Ok. I've posted an answer without RegEx.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about something like

```
@"([^\n\r]*)$"
```

That means match everything that is not a newline character till the end of the string.

Well, when I think about it, when you don't use the DOTALL modifier then this should be fine

```
@"(.*)$"
```

Without this modifier the `.` does not match newline characters. So no need for a `\n` at the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

Try it without a RegEx

```
string literal = @"I 
am
the
best"; //With \n

string[] lines = literal.Split(new string[] { "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
string lastLine = lines[lines.Length - 1];
Console.WriteLine(lastLine); //Should print "best"
```

With regex:

```
Match m = Regex.Match(literal, @"\n*.+$");
Console.WriteLine(m.Value); //Should be @"\nbest"
```

Comment: While splitting the string is a better solution in terms of complexity, this doesn't answer the question the OP asked.

Comment: Edited to answer the question as @George says.

Comment: Yes, second version worked. I had to choose the other answer because it responded first. Thanks!